# Designing T-Flipflop on Quartus

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I'm new to VHDL, and I wanna design a T Flip-Flip that toggles and change Q based on T input, and here is what I have

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


entity T_flipflop is

   Port ( T : in std_logic;
         CLK : in std_logic;
         Q : out std_logic ); 

end T_flipflop;


architecture Behavioral of T_flipflop is
 begin
  process (CLK) 
  --- The error in the following line
    if (CLK’event and CLK = ‘1’ )then
        Q <= Q when T = '0';
       Q <= not Q when T = '1';
    end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

But every time I run it on Quartus, I get the following errors, what am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance

```
Info: *******************************************************************
Info: Running Quartus Prime Analysis & Synthesis
    Info: Version 18.1.0 Build 625 09/12/2018 SJ Lite Edition
    Info: Processing started: Sun Dec 05 19:20:03 2021
    Info: Version 18.1.0 Build 625 09/12/2018 SJ Lite Edition
    Info: Processing started: Sun Dec 05 19:20:03 2021
Info: Command: quartus_map --read_settings_files=on --write_settings_files=off T_FlipFlop2 -c T_FlipFlop2
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Info (20030): Parallel compilation is enabled and will use 6 of the 6 processors detected
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at T_FlipFlop2.vhd(19) near text "if";  expecting "begin", or a declaration statement
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at T_FlipFlop2.vhd(19) near text 
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at T_FlipFlop2.vhd(19) near text 
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at T_FlipFlop2.vhd(19) near text 
Info (12021): Found 0 design units, including 0 entities, in source file t_flipflop2.vhd
Error: Quartus Prime Analysis & Synthesis was unsuccessful. 4 errors, 1 warning
    Error: Peak virtual memory: 4836 megabytes
    Error: Processing ended: Sun Dec 05 19:20:11 2021
    Error: Elapsed time: 00:00:08
    Error: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:18
    Error: Peak virtual memory: 4836 megabytes
    Error: Processing ended: Sun Dec 05 19:20:11 2021
    Error: Elapsed time: 00:00:08
    Error: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:18
Error (293001): Quartus Prime Full Compilation was unsuccessful. 6 errors, 1 warning
```

Comment: You don't show us the complete error messages. BTW, please copy all of it as text, not as screenshot. And where is "vhdl4.vhd"? Please mark the erroneous line(s) in the sources, for example by a comment.

Comment: Sorry for that, I just added the full error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process (CLK)` needs an `is begin`.

Change line 19 to:

`process (CLK) is begin`

Here is a reference for more info:  https://fpgatutorial.com/using-vhdl-process-blocks-to-model-sequential-logic/

Comment: Thank you so much, now I did that, two more errors poped up:  first at line 20 " if (CLK’event and CLK = ‘1’ )then " , and the error is ( Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at T_FlipFlop2.vhd(20) near text "";  expecting ")", or "," )

Comment: And the second at line 21 and 22 saying : " Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at T_FlipFlop2.vhd(21) near text "when";  expecting ";" : "

Comment: @Alselvdor Well, it seems that you need to take your VHDL book and look up the correct syntax.

Comment: `when` keyword is only allowed inside a process with VHDL 2008. Im not sure how much of VHDL 2008 Quartus Prime actually supports.

Comment: A process statement doesn't need an `is`, it's optional.The `begin` separates the process declarative part from the process statement part. As far as your link's tutorial accuracy, processes are concurrent statements. Blocks are separate concurrent statements representing hierarchy. An entity and it's architectures are elaborated into nested block statements. Blocks as processes comes from Systemverilog users.